# PHP array from checkbox values returns only Array instead of values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

According to suggestion here to use $_POST method to declare array from checkbox values I made it. But it isn't working.

In mysql table below, it stores only text that says Array. It doesn't store any of the values checked.

Even if I put echo like in the code below, it prints out "Array".

**HTML PAGE WITH QUESTIONNAIRE**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1[]" value="Mike">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1[]" value="Irena">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1[]" value="Sonya">

<input type="checkbox" name="cb2[]" value="Samsung">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2[]" value="Apple">
```

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
for($i=1;$i<101;$i++) {
    if(isset($_POST['cb'.$i])) {
        $row[$i] = $_POST['cb'.$i];
    }}
echo $row[1]; //it gives Array insted of values selected in the cb1

<?php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = "INSERT INTO storeresults(V1, V2) VALUES ('$row[1]','$row[2]')"; 
$db->setQuery($query); 
$db->query();
?>
```

Comment: Use `var_dump($row[1]);` instead, because the `$row[1]` is an array of the selected values. If you want to get the value you need to put it in another `for` loop

Comment: Do you want to insert each selected value as a record, or I think you want to join them with something like `,` then insert the joined value in DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your `name="cb1[]"`, your $_POST value will simply be `$_POST['cb1']`, which happens to be an array:

```
foreach($_POST['cb1'] as $key => $value) {
   echo $value; // spit out a name
   echo $_POST['cb1'][$key]; // same thing, in a different way
}
```

Plus, as written, your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).